# Troubleshooting my VueJS and Tailwind dropdownlist: why does it only work after page refresh?

Tags: vue.js, drop-down-menu, tailwind-css

I am building a VueJS frontend application, and I have a Tailwind dropdownlist in my main component. This component is loaded after user login successfully. Everything works fine, except the dropdownlist. It only works if I refresh the page.
I have add the `flowbite.js` everywhere but still cannot solve the problem. Following is my source code.

My script on Login page:

```html
<script>
import router from '../router'
import axios from 'axios'
export default
{
  data () {
    return {
      error: '',
      email: 'curatorL@iir.csie',
      password: '123'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    login () {
      var data = {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
      }
      axios.post('/api/login', data)
        .then((response) => {
          localStorage.setItem('user', response.data['token'])
          this.displayMenu = true
          router.push('/main')
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          this.error = 'Login Error'
          console.log(e.response.data)
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And this is my script on the main component:

```js
<template>
  <div v-if = "displayMenu" class="font-mono">
  <aside id="default-sidebar" class="fixed top-0 left-0 z-40 w-60 h-screen transition-transform -translate-x-full sm:translate-x-0" aria-label="Sidebar">
       <div class="h-full px-3 py-4 overflow-y-auto bg-gray-10 dark:bg-blue-800 flex-none">
          <ul class="space-y-2 font-medium">
             <li>
                <a @click.stop.prevent=" clickedItem=1 " href="#" class="flex items-center w-full p-2 text-gray-900 transition duration-75 rounded-lg group hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                   <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-6 h-6 text-gray-500 transition duration-75 dark:text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-900 dark:group-hover:text-white" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M2 10a8 8 0 018-8v8h8a8 8 0 11-16 0z"></path><path d="M12 2.252A8.014 8.014 0 0117.748 8H12V2.252z"></path></svg>
                   <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Dashboard</span>
                </a>
             </li>
             <li>
                <a @click.stop.prevent=" clickedItem=2 " class="flex items-center w-full p-2 text-gray-900 transition duration-75 rounded-lg group hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                   <svg aria-hidden="true" class="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 text-gray-500 transition duration-75 dark:text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-900 dark:group-hover:text-white" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M5 3a2 2 0 00-2 2v2a2 2 0 002 2h2a2 2 0 002-2V5a2 2 0 00-2-2H5zM5 11a2 2 0 00-2 2v2a2 2 0 002 2h2a2 2 0 002-2v-2a2 2 0 00-2-2H5zM11 5a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v2a2 2 0 01-2 2h-2a2 2 0 01-2-2V5zM11 13a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v2a2 2 0 01-2 2h-2a2 2 0 01-2-2v-2z"></path></svg>
                   <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Annotation</span>
                </a>
             </li>
             <li>
                <a @click.stop.prevent=" clickedItem=3 " class="flex items-center w-full p-2 text-gray-900 transition duration-75 rounded-lg group hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                   <svg aria-hidden="true" class="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 text-gray-500 transition duration-75 group-hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400 dark:group-hover:text-white" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M8.707 7.293a1 1 0 00-1.414 1.414l2 2a1 1 0 001.414 0l2-2a1 1 0 00-1.414-1.414L11 7.586V3a1 1 0 10-2 0v4.586l-.293-.293z"></path><path d="M3 5a2 2 0 012-2h1a1 1 0 010 2H5v7h2l1 2h4l1-2h2V5h-1a1 1 0 110-2h1a2 2 0 012 2v10a2 2 0 01-2 2H5a2 2 0 01-2-2V5z"></path></svg>
                   <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">Approval</span>
                </a>
             </li>
             <li>
                <button @click.stop.prevent=" clickedItem=4 " type="button" class="flex items-center w-full p-2 text-gray-900 transition duration-75 rounded-lg group hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700" aria-controls="user_subfunctions" data-collapse-toggle="user_subfunctions">
                  <svg aria-hidden="true" class="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 text-gray-500 transition duration-75 group-hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400 dark:group-hover:text-white" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M15 19.128a9.38 9.38 0 002.625.372 9.337 9.337 0 004.121-.952 4.125 4.125 0 00-7.533-2.493M15 19.128v-.003c0-1.113-.285-2.16-.786-3.07M15 19.128v.106A12.318 12.318 0 018.624 21c-2.331 0-4.512-.645-6.374-1.766l-.001-.109a6.375 6.375 0 0111.964-3.07M12 6.375a3.375 3.375 0 11-6.75 0 3.375 3.375 0 016.75 0zm8.25 2.25a2.625 2.625 0 11-5.25 0 2.625 2.625 0 015.25 0z"></path>
                  </svg>
                  <span class="flex-1 ml-3 text-left whitespace-nowrap" sidebar-toggle-item>User</span>
                  <svg sidebar-toggle-item class="w-6 h-6" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
                </button>
                <ul id="user_subfunctions" class="hidden py-2 space-y-2">
                      <li v-if="currentUser.role<2">
                         <a @click.stop.prevent=" clickedItem=41 " class="flex items-center w-full p-2 text-gray-900 transition duration-75 rounded-lg pl-11 group hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700">Create User</a>
                      </li>
                      <li v-if="currentUser.role<2">
                         <a @click.stop.prevent=" clickedItem=42 " class="flex items-center w-full p-2 text-gray-900 transition duration-75 rounded-lg pl-11 group hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700">User List</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                         <a @click.stop.prevent=" clickedItem=43 " class="flex items-center w-full p-2 text-gray-900 transition duration-75 rounded-lg pl-11 group hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700">Person Infor</a>
                      </li>
                </ul>
             </li>
             <li>
                <a @click.stop.prevent=" clickedItem=5 " class="flex items-center w-full p-2 text-gray-900 transition duration-75 rounded-lg group hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke-linejoin class="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 text-gray-500 transition duration-75 group-hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400 dark:group-hover:text-white" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M9.594 3.94c.09-.542.56-.94 1.11-.94h2.593c.55 0 1.02.398 1.11.94l.213 1.281c.063.374.313.686.645.87.074.04.147.083.22.127.324.196.72.257 1.075.124l1.217-.456a1.125 1.125 0 011.37.49l1.296 2.247a1.125 1.125 0 01-.26 1.431l-1.003.827c-.293.24-.438.613-.431.992a6.759 6.759 0 010 .255c-.007.378.138.75.43.99l1.005.828c.424.35.534.954.26 1.43l-1.298 2.247a1.125 1.125 0 01-1.369.491l-1.217-.456c-.355-.133-.75-.072-1.076.124a6.57 6.57 0 01-.22.128c-.331.183-.581.495-.644.869l-.213 1.28c-.09.543-.56.941-1.11.941h-2.594c-.55 0-1.02-.398-1.11-.94l-.213-1.281c-.062-.374-.312-.686-.644-.87a6.52 6.52 0 01-.22-.127c-.325-.196-.72-.257-1.076-.124l-1.217.456a1.125 1.125 0 01-1.369-.49l-1.297-2.247a1.125 1.125 0 01.26-1.431l1.004-.827c.292-.24.437-.613.43-.992a6.932 6.932 0 010-.255c.007-.378-.138-.75-.43-.99l-1.004-.828a1.125 1.125 0 01-.26-1.43l1.297-2.247a1.125 1.125 0 011.37-.491l1.216.456c.356.133.751.072 1.076-.124.072-.044.146-.087.22-.128.332-.183.582-.495.644-.869l.214-1.281z" />
                      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M15 12a3 3 0 11-6 0 3 3 0 016 0z" />
                    </svg>
                   <span class="flex-1 ml-3 whitespace-nowrap">System</span>
                </a>
             </li>
             <li>
                <a href="#" class="flex items-center p-2 text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                   <button class="flex-1 bg-blue-200 whitespace-nowrap rounded-lg" @click="logout()" type="button">Sign out</button>
                </a>
             </li>
          </ul>
       </div>
    </aside>
    <div class="sm:ml-60">
       <div class="border-2 border-gray-200 border-dashed rounded-lg dark:border-gray-700">
          <CreateAccount v-if="currentUser.role<2 && clickedItem == 41" />
        </div>
       </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import router from '../router'
import VueJwtDecode from 'vue-jwt-decode'
import axios from 'axios'
import CreateAccount from './CreateAccount.vue'
export default {
  components: {
    CreateAccount
  },
  data () {
    return {
      currentUser: '',
      displayMenu: false,
      clickedItem: 0
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('user')
    if (!token) {
      router.push('/')
    } else {
      var data = {token: token}
      axios.post('/api/verify', data)
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status === 201) {
            this.currentUser = VueJwtDecode.decode(token)
            this.displayMenu = true
            console.log(this.currentUser)
          } else {
            router.push('/')
          }
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          this.error = 'Login Error'
        })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    logout () {
      localStorage.removeItem('user')
      router.push('/')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I have search many examples about Sidebar, Tailwind and similar problems, but they didn't solve my problem

Comment: I found that the issue caused by v-if, but I am not able to solve it properly

Comment: Please put the code on codepen and share the link, it would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem now, just describe it here for someone may got the same issue.
This problem caused by v-if, which separate the components out of the DOM tree, and so that remove all its event handlers, in this case the @click event of the Tailwind dropdownlist (which is already implemented in flowbite.min.js).
My work around solution is that implement another method to control the event and place the code inside the component script.
My tailwind dropdownlist look like this:

```
<button id="userdropdown" type="button" @click="toggle()" class="flex items-center w-full p-2 text-gray-900 transition duration-75 rounded-lg group hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700" aria-controls="user_subfunctions" data-collapse-toggle="user_subfunctions">
              <svg aria-hidden="true" class="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 text-gray-500 transition duration-75 group-hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400 dark:group-hover:text-white" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M15 19.128a9.38 9.38 0 002.625.372 9.337 9.337 0 004.121-.952 4.125 4.125 0 00-7.533-2.493M15 19.128v-.003c0-1.113-.285-2.16-.786-3.07M15 19.128v.106A12.318 12.318 0 018.624 21c-2.331 0-4.512-.645-6.374-1.766l-.001-.109a6.375 6.375 0 0111.964-3.07M12 6.375a3.375 3.375 0 11-6.75 0 3.375 3.375 0 016.75 0zm8.25 2.25a2.625 2.625 0 11-5.25 0 2.625 2.625 0 015.25 0z"></path>
              </svg>
              <span class="flex-1 ml-3 text-left whitespace-nowrap" sidebar-toggle-item>User</span>
              <svg sidebar-toggle-item class="w-6 h-6" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
            </button>
            <ul id="usersubfunctions" ref="usersubfunctions" class="py-2 space-y-2">
                  <li v-if="currentUser.role<2">
                     <a @click.stop.prevent=" clickedItem=41 " class="flex items-center w-full p-2 text-gray-900 transition duration-75 rounded-lg pl-11 group hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700">Create User</a>
                  </li>
                  <li v-if="currentUser.role<2">
                     <a @click.stop.prevent=" clickedItem=42 " class="flex items-center w-full p-2 text-gray-900 transition duration-75 rounded-lg pl-11 group hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700">User List</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     <a @click.stop.prevent=" clickedItem=43 " class="flex items-center w-full p-2 text-gray-900 transition duration-75 rounded-lg pl-11 group hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700">User Profile</a>
                  </li>
            </ul>
```

Notice that the it contains a button with id = 'userdropdown' and a  list with id='usersubfunctions'. So now, we re-implement the event by method like this:

```
 methods: {
toggle () {
  let usersubfunctions = document.querySelector('#usersubfunctions')
  if (usersubfunctions.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    usersubfunctions.classList.remove('hidden')
  } else {
    usersubfunctions.classList.add('hidden')
  }
}
```

That it is, I solve the problem like that.